# Location of Xcode Bots configuration files

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots

I need to copy and transfer integration settings (trigger script, actually) from one to another project, but since my development Mac isn't connected to OS X Server, I can't check out Bot settings and take that script from existing project.

Is there a way to find Bot's configuration files? And where they are actually stored at (dev machine or server)?

I tried to look at

```
~/Library/Developer/XcodeServer
```

but found only bunch of .log files for every integration

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this using the newer version of Xcode Server, even though Xcode Server now runs as a specific user, the configuration files are kept in `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer`.  You can also hit the [Xcode Server API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/Integrations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016472-CH3-SW1) to get information about your bots.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know that this approach can work properly, however, my suggestion would be "export and import XCode configuration file". That can be understood as after your project completed configuration, start exporting "xconfig" files and then import to your other projects. 
This link might be helpful [Is there a way export xcode build settings to .xcconfig file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164876/is-there-a-way-export-xcode-build-settings-to-xcconfig-file/20862973#20862973)

Comment: unfortunately project.pbxproj doesn't contain any server-related information